# SQL Server minimum value within column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have `table_1` with the following data:

```
| STORE | Add | dis | Cnt | 
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|   101 | X   | abc | 2   | 
|   101 | X   | null| 3   | 
|   101 | X   |pqrd | 4   | 
|   101 | X   | null| 1   | 
|   102 | y   | null| 1   | 
|   102 | y   | xyz | 3   | 
|   102 | y   | pqr | 4   | 
|   102 | y   | null| 2   |
```

I tried to build a query to get data from table_1 where [dis] is not null and [cnt] should be minumum. So my result should looks like below:

```
| STORE | Add | dis | Cnt | 
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|   101 | X   | abc | 2   | 
|   102 | y   | xyz | 3   |
```

My query looks like below :

```
SELECT store,add,dis,min(TMPLT_PRIORITY_NMBR)
FROM table_1 group by store,add;
```

But I get the following error:

> Column 'dis' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I use [dis] in GROUP BY clause, I get the wrong result and giving max(dis) or min(dis) also provides the wrong result.

What would be the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rank` to find the row with the minimal `cnt` value per store/add combination, and return all the columns from it:

```
SELECT store, add, dis, cnt
FROM   (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY store, add ORDER BY cnt) AS rk
        FROM   table_1
        WHERE  dis IS NOT NULL) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `first_value` and `min` with `over`:

```
SELECT distinct store,
       add,
       first_value(dis) over(partition by store, add order by Cnt) as dis,
       min(Cnt) over(partition by store, add) as cnt
FROM table_1
```